# Can't change height of image, while using expanded widget

Tags: image, flutter, dart, expander

Im trying to change the height of an image but when i change height only size of the container changes but the height of image stays the same.

```
Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: 250,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,

                      // child: Padding(
                      // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Image(
                        height: 150,
                        // width: 100,
                        image: AssetImage("images/MiddleEarthWp.jpg"),
                      ),
                      // ),
                    )),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 7,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

[Before changing height of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe5uq.png)  and [After changing a height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGzCN.png)

Answer (score 0):

you're having this because your image is a child of the container and because you didnt specify the fit of the image , you can try this code :

```
Container(
  // background to this Container.
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    image: new DecorationImage(
      image: new AssetImage('images/background.png'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
```